# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.Error

Tags: python

```
import os

from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pdf_dir = (r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Dataset\Test")
os.chdir(pdf_dir)

for pdf_file in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Dataset\Test"):

    if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf"):

        pages = convert_from_path(pdf_file, 300)
        pdf_file = pdf_file[:-4]

        for page in pages:
            page.save("%s-page%d.jpg" % (pdf_file,pages.index(page)), "JPEG")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Why don't you take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There's too much code and any explanation here. Try also to adjust your formatting please.

Comment: As a new user here, also take the [tour]. Questions like yours also require a [mcve].

Comment: Can you also include error you are facing?, This will help community to help/guide you finding solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a print statement to debug at each step, to see exactly which files are not present/ error with the directory name. For example -

```
for pdf_file in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Dataset\Test"):
    print(pdf_file)  ###1st step to see if your path contains relevant files

    if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf"):

        pages = convert_from_path(pdf_file, 300)  ##If the error is at this line, try adding the complete path, rather than file name
        pdf_file = pdf_file[:-4]
        print(pdf_file) ## See what is the pdf file name extracted

    for page in pages:
        print(page) ## See whats the value of page generated
        page.save("%s-page%d.jpg" % (pdf_file,pages.index(page)), "JPEG")
```

This is the basic idea to debug, which has helped me in the past. You question doesnt describe the complete error, which file is not present. Hence, the generic approach.

Hope it helps.

Comment: adding log/print always help in debugging, can you suggest something to avoid/handle error user has facing

Comment: This is obviously not the solution to any error, this is only approach to identify error

Comment: Need the detailed error description, to see exactly which line is causing the error, hence i've suggested this approach , given the deails.